# Writing equations (Mathjax and alternatives)

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

How important does everyone feel that equations are here?  Other communities like physics and math uses MathJax, which will render equations typed in LaTeX.  That has to be added to the site code, and I admit I do not know how this is done.

As a PSA, I use the [quicklatex](http://quicklatex.com/) site when the MathJax isn't available.  You can paste LaTeX there and then it will produce an image with a URL, you can use the URL directly to put the equation in your answer.  It's certainly better than writing it out in plain text.

Comment: We need them. This IS the Rocket Science after all!

Comment: Having access to MathJax is a great means to improve clarity of expression. Oh, and to boast that my Delta-Vee is much greater than yours.

Comment: Pinging again (puhleese, pretty please...) Answering gets very difficult without MathJax.

Comment: Dear AlanSE... First, I support this. And, you can find a script [in Manish's post](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/89/1414) over Chem.SE. It lets your browser to render MathJax for you. The problem is, it isn't automatic. Add the script to your bookmarks and click it whenever you see a page with `$$` around. As it's browser-based, it can be used anywhere (say, Facebook). Just a suggestion for now :D

Comment: Robert! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 15):

Nice Job. You put together a good proposal. This has been…

$$
\Huge DONE
$$

Comment: _"That’s one small step for $$\text{[a]}$$ man, one giant leap for $$\text{[Space Exploration]}$$ mankind!"_

Comment: @TildalWave: What's the `$$` double line for??? *(Flagging as obsolete)* and *not constructive* :P

Answer (score 13):

This is a community-wiki post that everyone can edit.

---

### List of questions worth answering with MathJax

- DONE? [Energy cost of bringing the space shuttle external tank to orbit](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/264/energy-cost-of-bringing-the-space-shuttle-external-tank-to-orbit)
- [How much fuel would one need to launch a 1kg object from 100,000 feet?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/438/how-much-fuel-would-one-need-to-launch-a-1kg-object-from-100-000-feet)
- [How possible are 'space jumps'?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/511/how-possible-are-space-jumps)
- [What is the probability of impact?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/725/25)
- [Effect of atmospheric drag on rocket launches and benefits of high altitude launch sites](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/744/effect-of-atmospheric-drag-on-rocket-launches)
- [Liquid micrometeorites compared to solids](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/784/liquid-micrometeorites-compared-to-solids)
- [In space can the difference in temperature between the inside and outside, provide useful energy?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/795/in-space-can-the-difference-in-temperature-between-the-inside-and-outside-provi)
- DONE? [How do you weigh things in a micro-gravity environment?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/911/how-do-you-weigh-things-in-the-weightiness-of-space)
- [What coordinate system is used in space for navigation?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/969/what-coordinate-system-is-used-in-space-for-navigation)
- DONE? [How can the optimal number of satellites in an orbital plane be determined?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1081/how-to-determine-the-optimal-number-of-satellites-in-an-orbital-plane)
- https://space.stackexchange.com/a/1131/25 (Already has markup!)
- [Gravity drag Delta-v calculation for launches to orbit](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1345/gravity-drag-delta-v-calculation-for-launches-to-orbit)

Answer (score 6):

I feel that they're very important here. Take, for example, this type of question:

> With an ion drive engine, how long would it take to get to Pluto?

Or better yet,

> How much uranium would I need to get to [planet]?

In both these cases, formulas would be very important. I was quite disappointed when I tried to use the `$$` syntax on a formula, only to have it fail.

Comment: Even biology has MathJax, and there's actually a good point over on biology meta: if you don't have MathJax, it can discourage people from posting questions that require equations: http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/questions/7/shall-we-have-mathjax

Comment: Also, the rocket equation!: http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/123/why-is-launching-objects-out-of-the-earth-so-expensive

Answer (score 5):

Space exploration is physics, so math notation is just as important here.

I don't understand the hesitation.  I can see no degradation in performance on the math, physics, or mathematica stackexchange pages.

No apparent downside, and dramatic benefits in the clarity of answers.

Answer: *very important*.

Answer (score 4):

MathJax will slow down the page rendering speed by some margin.

AFAIK the sites supporting MathJax are: Math, Physics, Stat, Mathematica, CS, EE, and some beta sites like scicomp and cogsci.

However I don't see a significant slow down (except Math.SE) while my browser rendering a page having equations on these sites vs other sites (like TeX.SE). I have a 5 year old desktop using Ubuntu 12.04 and Chromium running on Q6700+4G DDR2 800Mhz RAM.

I suggest that if this SE reaches a point that there are tens of questions which can be answered with equations, MathJax support should be implemented.

Comment: Here is an example of a question that gets considerable slowdown from equations, because several people wrote an answer heavy on equations: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/8074/why-is-the-earth-so-fat  I agree, questions like that are a rarity.

Comment: @SF. I made a new answer using community-wiki, you can edit it now as well. :)

Comment: Deleted comments accordingly. As for slowdown, while displaying equation-heavy page is not a big problem, editing an equation-heavy post is. While writing http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/46318/is-there-a-small-enough-planet-or-asteroid-you-can-orbit-by-jumping/46325#46325 I was really getting ired at the lag, but I believe the benefits outweigh the costs.

Comment: @SF. Haha, in math.SE there are all kinds of slowdowns. Some equation heavy answer I wrote does get severe slowdown: for eg [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/392322/relation-of-the-kernels-of-one-bounded-operator-and-its-extension). What I do is normally making the draft in a text-editor on my computer then ctrl+c/v.

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be a good feature, but I'm not sure how many questions we will have here that would make use of the ability to write equations.  If we were to have a number of those types of questions, I feel it would be very useful.

Comment: I could imagine quite a few questions may have a need for it - my question would be how many of those would be a better fit on Physics?

Comment: @RoryAlsop Physics also incorporated the failed astronomy questions into it.  Between all 3 topics you could draw Venn Diagrams.  I expect to see many questions that could go either way.

Comment: I asked the meta question anyway - http://meta.space.stackexchange.com/questions/12/where-is-our-demarcation-line-between-space-exploration-and-physics