# Collaborative math

Tags: discussion

Questions like this one [Energy cost of bringing the space shuttle external tank to orbit](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/264/energy-cost-of-bringing-the-space-shuttle-external-tank-to-orbit) make me wish there was some sort of embeddable collaborative math option.  Something that would let you create a Mathematica/Sage/MathCAD documents, embed them in a question/answer, and allow others to fork it with suggested edits.

Anyone know of something like this?

**Update**: The closest I have seen for this is [Mathics](http://www.mathics.net/).

Comment: You mean like something based on MathML?

Comment: http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/questions/912/can-we-get-mathml-support. I think that just being able to provide relistic looking equations would be a benefit.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't a way to do *exactly* what you're asking, but there *could* be a way to write equations.

You see, there is this really cool thing called Mathjax (Google it!), which allows you to write really amazing looking formulae, etc.

However, it is only enabled where Stack Exchange feels it is needed. We are trying to get it enabled for this site in [this discussion](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7/writing-equations-mathjax-and-alternatives).

Comment: That is a step in the right direction.