# Would it be useful to be able to put videos in questions and answers?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

I was going to do this the other day with two videos of the Antares explosion this week. The question regarded analysis of the video so it would have been relevant.

It occurs to me that animations of trajectories and orbits could be useful in some answers. Cases dealing with airflow, dynamic loads - potentially there are applications, it seems more a question of how often it would be used.

Edit - This feature is now available for YouTube videos. If a video complies with the quality standards listed in TildalWave's answer, embed it by putting **the address as shown in your browser's address bar** into the question or answer. The address as shown when you press the 'share' button on YouTube won't work. If you want the video to begin at a certain time, **add &t=xmxxs to the end of the address**, where x is the number of minutes and xx is the number of seconds. (If you use the short cut of right-clicking over the video and then selecting 'copy video URL at current time', it may give you an address that starts with 'youtu.be'. That won't work.)

Comment: As a corollary, when a video is posted it would be nice to have a mandatory field to move the tick to. Something like "See launch video clip beginning 1:23 ending 1:48"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I definitely support this. I've [suggested this before](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/9682?m=16609865#16609865), but considering the opportunity (our first birthday), everyone, [including yours truly](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/16618686#16618686), seems to have been taken over by the idea of receiving an [even nicer gift](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/16612681#16612681) for the occasion. Or course, nothing came out of that. But hey, one can dream. :)

More seriously though, yes, in my opinion, it could make a nice addition to our site's features. I don't see it as problematic in terms of substantially increasing bandwidth, client or server load (even enabling MathJax isn't really anymore in this day and age not even on smartphones), and it's definitely possible. Some other Stack Exchange sites (including beta ones) already have similar implemented / enabled, for example [Video Production](https://video.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190/youtube-and-soundcloud-embedding-is-now-enabled) has the ability to embed YouTube videos and SoundCloud audio streams directly in posts and through links alone that are then parsed and videos in links embedded on submit (that means no preview during editing tho).

There is however a slight concern that enabling YouTube video embedding within our posts might lead to increased frequency of low quality contributions where videos will be used to substitute written word, or even to promote one's own YouTube channel or help spread video annotations and descriptions spam. This is something we should be vigilant about during our peer reviews and demand quality just like we always did. Also note that while displaying embedded video thumbnails and the player alone isn't too bandwidth demanding, playing long ones to review their contents or follow the contribution's narrative might be to some, especially those on bandwidth throttling, download capping or PAYG mobile carriers. So here's a few ground rules I believe are reasonable and we should all abide to (including yours truly):

- **Don't embed videos as centerpieces of your contributions and include transcripts!**
  Not everyone will be able or will have the time to watch full-length videos you'll be embedding. We also want answers in text and explaining what the video you link or are directly embedding will present and how is it relevant to what you're trying to say in your contribution. Including a video should never serve to replace a properly written question or answer, it should merely complement it and make it easier to understand! Rule of a thumb here is that your contribution should still remain valid, complete and comprehensible even if the video becomes unavailable at a later date.
- **Remember to attribute video's source and authorship, just like you'd do with images!**
  Not every video embedded will require this, but please check with your source if that's the case. Last thing we want to enable with this is content theft, abuse of authorship, disrespect publisher rights or distributor's terms of service. Just because some video is easy to embed, it doesn't mean that we're at liberty to do so. Also note that some materials can include copyright flags, demographic or other restrictions at a later than publishing date and won't play in embedded players anymore because of this. If you think that with some video it sounds too good to be true to be available without restrictions for everyone, it probably is. Please follow up on posts where you included such videos and respond to comments notifying you of their unavailability.
- **Not every linked to video needs embedding, we can still link to them in text only!**
   Some linked videos will only serve as an additional point of reference, aren't following the narrative of your contribution and, if they were displayed all over it, would detract from its true purpose. Please only use embedded videos where you deem are absolutely essential to what you want to present in your contribution, or, as an alternative reason, they use a video preview thumbnail that you'd include in your answer anyway for illustrative purposes.
- **Avoid embedding videos of poor quality or ones that promote products or services!**
  This includes videos that use excessive number of in-video annotations that link to other pages, videos that are primarily made to attract attention to the YouTube channel they were posted on, videos that are otherwise too pushy in any respect, that are of poor quality (inaudible, unable to see much, too loud,...) or are too lengthy and most of their contents aren't relevant to what you'd like to show us. Note that most popular videos are also republished to include spam or promote other non-relevant causes. If you can, find the best quality original, from a trusted publisher.
- **Watch out for shaddy, low rep publishers, and inappropriate content like "video bombs"!**
  Please watch the video in full before posting it on the site, embedded or not, and pay attention to inappropriate contents. That includes the so-called "video bombs" or the publisher being prone to replacing video preview thumbnails with inappropriate ones at a later date to try and bring additional attention to them. If you're unsure, look through the publisher's channel, sort by most popular videos, and see if any of them seem suspicious in that regard.
- **If there's only a part of the video that's relevant, please embed it with a time link!**
  Sometimes, you'll want to show us a short part of an otherwise lengthy video. It will be possible to embed videos so they start playing at some specified time, please see below how to do that:

Together with [@AJ Henderson](https://video.stackexchange.com/users/2836/aj-henderson), moderator on Video Production, [we've also tested](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18563526#18563526) this parser's ability to display YouTube videos and start playing at specified position. Sadly, this doesn't work via a `#` URL hook as YouTube gives addresses to videos when you click on its *Copy video URL at current time* link, but simply replacing the `#` hook with `&` to add a new parameter to the URL does work. Here's [a working example](https://video.stackexchange.com/q/7131/3536) of that.

I've also asked about this our Community Manager (quite some time ago) and, if I remember correctly, we simply need to ask for it like we did to [enable MathJax](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7/writing-equations-mathjax-and-alternatives). We currently don't have all too many [posts linking to YouTube videos](https://space.stackexchange.com/search?q=youtube), but reading some, it would certainly make them easier to follow if readers didn't have to open a new tab / page in their browsers. So yes, I'm in it. And with your support, I'll be on it as well. ;)

Comment: The concern with this isn't bandwidth or server load (YouTube seems to have plenty of both unless you're stuck with a really crappy ISP). Rather, the concern is that folks will post videos in lieu of explanations, making posts that are less accessible initially and potentially worthless if the video goes down. So the trick here is to demonstrate that videos will be used effectively to augment posts and won't be abused to replace them.

Comment: The concern is born of the fact that some folks have wanted this feature enabled *for the express purpose* of posting such answers (or questions), TidalWave. If you're committed to preventing such things, *and* have examples of posts where video would augment a complete answer, that goes a long way toward justifying it.

Comment: Just edit your answer to summarize this conversation.

Comment: Solid guidelines, Tidal. Make 'em happen!

Answer (score 7):

This is a community wiki list of questions/answers linking to YouTube videos (current search results for [`url:*youtu.be*`](https://space.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A*youtu.be*) and [`url:*youtube.com*`](https://space.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A*youtube.com*) queries):

---

#### Questions (in alphabetical order):

- [Q: “Lunar vacuum cleaner”: Design considerations for regolith dust suction system in exospheric…](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/5555/lunar-vacuum-cleaner-design-considerations-for-regolith-dust-suction-system-i)
- [Q: Benefits of hydrogen cannon for first stage launch at sea level or 20,000 feet](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/6241/benefits-of-hydrogen-cannon-for-first-stage-launch-at-sea-level-or-20-000-feet)
- [Q: Can a booster be designed to withstand 10,000 Gs?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3680/can-a-booster-be-designed-to-withstand-10-000-gs)
- [Q: Convergent-Divergent / De Laval Nozzle Dimensions](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/4337/convergent-divergent-de-laval-nozzle-dimensions)
- [Q: Could an Apollo astronaut have put their foot through the hull of the LEM?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/6432/could-an-apollo-astronaut-have-put-their-foot-through-the-hull-of-the-lem)
- [Q: Could an upcoming comet lander be designed to cope with a greater variety of terrain types, …](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/5954/could-an-upcoming-comet-lander-be-designed-to-cope-with-a-greater-variety-of-ter)
- [Q: Did something go wrong during the Soyuz TMA-13M launch?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/4635/did-something-go-wrong-during-the-soyuz-tma-13m-launch)
- [Q: Didn't Wernher von Braun understand Kepler's laws in 1955?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/6143/didnt-wernher-von-braun-understand-keplers-laws-in-1955)
- [Q: Do the ISS crew also study Russian language?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/6404/do-the-iss-crew-also-study-russian-language)
- [Q: Do the majority of astronauts experience space sickness while adapting to micro-gravitationa…](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1189/do-the-majority-of-astronauts-experience-space-sickness-while-adapting-to-micro)
- [Q: Does Redstone start sequence involve a key?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2165/does-redstone-start-sequence-involve-a-key)
- [Q: Does the space shuttle fly straight “up” when leaving Earth?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/4085/does-the-space-shuttle-fly-straight-up-when-leaving-earth)
- [Q: Electromagnetic Propulsion Technology](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1736/electromagnetic-propulsion-technology)
- [Q: Finding rocket transfer function for rocket stabilization](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/5621/finding-rocket-transfer-function-for-rocket-stabilization)
- [Q: Have any animals that have been studied onboard the ISS came back alive?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3262/have-any-animals-that-have-been-studied-onboard-the-iss-came-back-alive)
- [Q: How big of a problem is the Lunar eclipse in April 2014 for LADEE?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1734/how-big-of-a-problem-is-the-lunar-eclipse-in-april-2014-for-ladee)
- [Q: How do astronauts battle loss in blood volume in microgravity?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2611/how-do-astronauts-battle-loss-in-blood-volume-in-microgravity)
- [Q: How should one analyze the video of the Antares CRS-3 explosion to find the clues to the cause?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/5735/how-should-one-analyze-the-video-of-the-antares-crs-3-explosion-to-find-the-clue)
- [Q: How were vibrations supposed to be handled in an Ares I?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1485/how-were-vibrations-supposed-to-be-handled-in-an-ares-i)
- [Q: Is this really Rosetta's orbit around 67P?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/5117/is-this-really-rosettas-orbit-around-67p)
- [Q: My space station is filling with water](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/5421/my-space-station-is-filling-with-water)
- [Q: Nuclear powered engines with LFTR technology?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/4571/nuclear-powered-engines-with-lftr-technology)
- [Q: Progress M-25M launched because of Antares?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/5748/progress-m-25m-launched-because-of-antares)
- [Q: Reasons for using a bi-elliptic transfer for Soyuz-ISS rendezvous](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/6542/reasons-for-using-a-bi-elliptic-transfer-for-soyuz-iss-rendezvous)
- [Q: Was any first stage recovery system tested on SpaceX Falcon 9 flight seven?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3035/was-any-first-stage-recovery-system-tested-on-spacex-falcon-9-flight-seven)
- [Q: Were the Lunokhod Lunar rovers remote controlled in real time?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/4993/were-the-lunokhod-lunar-rovers-remote-controlled-in-real-time)
- [Q: What are the risks involved in amateur high-altitude ballooning, and how can we mitigate them?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2213/what-are-the-risks-involved-in-amateur-high-altitude-ballooning-and-how-can-we)
- [Q: What are the tradeoffs of docking multiple small launches in orbit vs a single heavy launch?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/6014/what-are-the-tradeoffs-of-docking-multiple-small-launches-in-orbit-vs-a-single-h)
- [Q: What entails “Avionics” on the Antares Rocket?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/5732/what-entails-avionics-on-the-antares-rocket)
- [Q: What is sprayed at a rocket launch? And why? [duplicate]](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/4989/what-is-sprayed-at-a-rocket-launch-and-why)
- [Q: What is the range of strength for asteroidal materials?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/605/what-is-the-range-of-strength-for-asteroidal-materials)
- [Q: What is this red gas at the exhaust of the Long March 3B rocket during liftoff?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2982/what-is-this-red-gas-at-the-exhaust-of-the-long-march-3b-rocket-during-liftoff)
- [Q: What was the first rocket to use gimbaled thrust?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/5689/what-was-the-first-rocket-to-use-gimbaled-thrust)
- [Q: What were the circumstances of this impact event on Jupiter in 2012?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1779/what-were-the-circumstances-of-this-impact-event-on-jupiter-in-2012)
- [Q: What would be the delta-v of rendezvousing with temporarily captured asteroids in Sun-Earth …](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/5192/what-would-be-the-delta-v-of-rendezvousing-with-temporarily-captured-asteroids-i)
- [Q: Where should a lunar polar ISRU mission land?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/4551/where-should-a-lunar-polar-isru-mission-land)
- [Q: Who really coined the phrase “Light the Candle!” to commence with a rocket launch?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3263/who-really-coined-the-phrase-light-the-candle-to-commence-with-a-rocket-launc)
- [Q: Why did a flight controller say “Avionics power nominal” as Antares exploded?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/5733/why-did-a-flight-controller-say-avionics-power-nominal-as-antares-exploded)
- [Q: Why did the Saturn V stage fairing appear to burn after separation?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3987/why-did-the-saturn-v-stage-fairing-appear-to-burn-after-separation)
- [Q: Why does NASA intentionally spin space probes?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2383/why-does-nasa-intentionally-spin-space-probes)
- [Q: Why does the Soyuz cover its main engine?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/5403/why-does-the-soyuz-cover-its-main-engine)
- [Q: Why dont we use catapults to get to space?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/5463/why-dont-we-use-catapults-to-get-to-space)

#### Answers (in alphabetical order):

- [A: Alternative data transfer channels for inter-stellar probes?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/601/alternative-data-transfer-channels-for-inter-stellar-probes/3589#3589)
- [A: Are any precautions in place to prevent loss of the Rosetta Lander the way Hayabusa's MINERV…](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2771/are-any-precautions-in-place-to-prevent-loss-of-the-rosetta-lander-the-way-hayab/3184#3184)
- [A: Are there any safety procedures in place on the ISS in case of puncture?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/881/are-there-any-safety-procedures-in-place-on-the-iss-in-case-of-puncture/910#910)
- [A: Artificial objects longer than 40 meters in space](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1001/artificial-objects-longer-than-40-meters-in-space/1002#1002)
- [A: At what angle did Apollo 13 need to reenter?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3058/at-what-angle-did-apollo-13-need-to-reenter/3059#3059)
- [A: Can a free falling astronaut change his spin and orientation?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/6282/can-a-free-falling-astronaut-change-his-spin-and-orientation/6289#6289)
- [A: Can New Horizons be turned into an orbiter for the Pluto system?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/4634/can-new-horizons-be-turned-into-an-orbiter-for-the-pluto-system/4636#4636)
- [A: Can you have birthday cake in space?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/812/can-you-have-birthday-cake-in-space/813#813)
- [A: Cause of ISRO MOM's LAM shutdown during the 4th orbit raising manoeuvre](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3524/cause-of-isro-moms-lam-shutdown-during-the-4th-orbit-raising-manoeuvre/5627#5627)
- [A: Challenges Facing Hybrid Rocketry](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3960/challenges-facing-hybrid-rocketry/5842#5842)
- [A: Could a skyhook be used to remove space junk?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1206/could-a-skyhook-be-used-to-remove-space-junk/3813#3813)
- [A: Could I tie together two satellites at different altitudes?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/5396/could-i-tie-together-two-satellites-at-different-altitudes/5397#5397)
- [A: Curiosity's powered descent stage test](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3688/curiositys-powered-descent-stage-test/3689#3689)
- [A: Did Curiosity rover communicate to the ground station during its descent phase?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1339/did-curiosity-rover-communicate-to-the-ground-station-during-its-descent-phase/1377#1377)
- [A: Do any spacecraft use carkeys?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2108/do-any-spacecraft-use-carkeys/2109#2109)
- [A: Do astronauts aboard the International Space Station (ISS) actually use their legs?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2412/do-astronauts-aboard-the-international-space-station-iss-actually-use-their-le/2448#2448)
- [A: Do humans need less calories and water in microgravity?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/5125/do-humans-need-less-calories-and-water-in-microgravity/5127#5127)
- [A: Do lunar landers communicate with ground stations during descent and landing?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3134/do-lunar-landers-communicate-with-ground-stations-during-descent-and-landing/3135#3135)
- [A: Do rocket exhaust plumes really provide a pathway for lightning?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1968/do-rocket-exhaust-plumes-really-provide-a-pathway-for-lightning/1976#1976)
- [A: Does Mars One plan on taking precautions to ensure the Martian environment is not contaminat…](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/4304/does-mars-one-plan-on-taking-precautions-to-ensure-the-martian-environment-is-no/4305#4305)
- [A: Does the space shuttle fly straight “up” when leaving Earth?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/4085/does-the-space-shuttle-fly-straight-up-when-leaving-earth/4097#4097)
- [A: Efficient types of nozzles used in rockets](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1171/efficient-types-of-nozzles-used-in-rockets/1190#1190)
- [A: Finding rocket transfer function for rocket stabilization](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/5621/finding-rocket-transfer-function-for-rocket-stabilization/5720#5720)
- [A: Folding structures in space - What are the potential benefits and problems?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/4440/folding-structures-in-space-what-are-the-potential-benefits-and-problems/4452#4452)
- [A: For a 3 booster rocket, why do they start with igniting the starboard booster, followed by t…](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1652/for-a-3-booster-rocket-why-do-they-start-with-igniting-the-starboard-booster-f/1653#1653)
- [A: Has there ever been done research on mechanical assisted landing and takeoff?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3193/has-there-ever-been-done-research-on-mechanical-assisted-landing-and-takeoff/3438#3438)
- [A: How can spacecraft navigate without contact from Earth?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/942/how-can-spacecraft-navigate-without-contact-from-earth/944#944)
- [A: How could one navigate on Mars?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2570/how-could-one-navigate-on-mars/2575#2575)
- [A: How did they test early spacesuits in a vacuum?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3060/how-did-they-test-early-spacesuits-in-a-vacuum/3061#3061)
- [A: How do astronauts drink or eat in space?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1352/how-do-astronauts-drink-or-eat-in-space/1355#1355)
- [A: How do astronauts turn in space?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2954/how-do-astronauts-turn-in-space/2970#2970)
- [A: How do people drink out of cups in Space?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/135/how-do-people-drink-out-of-cups-in-space/140#140)
- [A: How do people drink out of cups in Space?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/135/how-do-people-drink-out-of-cups-in-space/139#139)
- [A: How does a thin metal rocket engine not get crushed by the weight of the flying rocket?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/4108/how-does-a-thin-metal-rocket-engine-not-get-crushed-by-the-weight-of-the-flying/5493#5493)
- [A: How does astronaut activity from within affect a spacecraft?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/690/how-does-astronaut-activity-from-within-affect-a-spacecraft/709#709)
- [A: How does astronaut activity from within affect a spacecraft?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/690/how-does-astronaut-activity-from-within-affect-a-spacecraft/701#701)
- [A: How does liquified natural gas compare to liquid methane?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/5372/how-does-liquified-natural-gas-compare-to-liquid-methane/5375#5375)
- [A: How does plant growing medium not scatter around?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3379/how-does-plant-growing-medium-not-scatter-around/3380#3380)
- [A: How does Rosetta “wake-up?”](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3443/how-does-rosetta-wake-up/3644#3644)
- [A: How fast can the crew evacuate the ISS? (ACRV)](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/5771/how-fast-can-the-crew-evacuate-the-iss-acrv/6620#6620)
- [A: How frequently do asteroids collide with each other?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1382/how-frequently-do-asteroids-collide-with-each-other/1388#1388)
- [A: How is spin stability used in spacecraft?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/867/how-is-spin-stability-used-in-spacecraft/895#895)
- [A: How is the periscope port on Soyuz spacecraft secured for the atmospheric reentry?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3232/how-is-the-periscope-port-on-soyuz-spacecraft-secured-for-the-atmospheric-reentr/3233#3233)
- [A: How many airlocks does the ISS have?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3205/how-many-airlocks-does-the-iss-have/4296#4296)
- [A: How much of a problem is space junk, and how can we clean it up?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/19/how-much-of-a-problem-is-space-junk-and-how-can-we-clean-it-up/4194#4194)
- [A: How should one analyze the video of the Antares CRS-3 explosion to find the clues to the cause?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/5735/how-should-one-analyze-the-video-of-the-antares-crs-3-explosion-to-find-the-clue/5759#5759)
- [A: How were vibrations supposed to be handled in an Ares I?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1485/how-were-vibrations-supposed-to-be-handled-in-an-ares-i/1632#1632)
- [A: How will Juno establish existence of solid core within Jupiter and determine its size?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3676/how-will-juno-establish-existence-of-solid-core-within-jupiter-and-determine-its/3682#3682)
- [A: How would one go about proving humans have really been to outer space?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2433/how-would-one-go-about-proving-humans-have-really-been-to-outer-space/2434#2434)
- [A: Humans surviving in space](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/6037/humans-surviving-in-space/6045#6045)
- [A: Is flight software shared among different spacecraft?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2388/is-flight-software-shared-among-different-spacecraft/2407#2407)
- [A: Is it possible to perform the Galileo's Leaning Tower of Pisa experiment on the Moon?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2097/is-it-possible-to-perform-the-galileos-leaning-tower-of-pisa-experiment-on-the/6423#6423)
- [A: Is it possible to perform the Galileo's Leaning Tower of Pisa experiment on the Moon?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2097/is-it-possible-to-perform-the-galileos-leaning-tower-of-pisa-experiment-on-the/2098#2098)
- [A: Is there any footage of the rocket that launched Sputnik 1?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3640/is-there-any-footage-of-the-rocket-that-launched-sputnik-1/3646#3646)
- [A: Is there any non-rocket spacelaunch concept within reach of current material science and tec…](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3033/is-there-any-non-rocket-spacelaunch-concept-within-reach-of-current-material-sci/3034#3034)
- [A: Is there research for the optimal small crew size for a long space voyage?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/446/is-there-research-for-the-optimal-small-crew-size-for-a-long-space-voyage/938#938)
- [A: Is this really Rosetta's orbit around 67P?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/5117/is-this-really-rosettas-orbit-around-67p/5118#5118)
- [A: Is warp drive a legitimate avenue of scientific investigation?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/982/is-warp-drive-a-legitimate-avenue-of-scientific-investigation/983#983)
- [A: Is winged flight possible in low/zero G environment?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2614/is-winged-flight-possible-in-low-zero-g-environment/2617#2617)
- [A: Mars Semi Direct](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/6649/mars-semi-direct/6650#6650)
- [A: Methods for propulsion other than rockets for leaving Earth's atmosphere?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/203/methods-for-propulsion-other-than-rockets-for-leaving-earths-atmosphere/4652#4652)
- [A: Objects speeding up due to planets gravity?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/5727/objects-speeding-up-due-to-planets-gravity/5728#5728)
- [A: Reaction to taking a glove off in space](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/122/reaction-to-taking-a-glove-off-in-space/126#126)
- [A: Through what mechanisms would SpaceX test and examine the returned CRS-5 first stage?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/6111/through-what-mechanisms-would-spacex-test-and-examine-the-returned-crs-5-first-s/6112#6112)
- [A: Vertical-takeoff, vertical-landing (VTVL) vehicle falling orientation](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/667/vertical-takeoff-vertical-landing-vtvl-vehicle-falling-orientation/676#676)
- [A: Washing clothes in space: are there any technical challenges?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/653/washing-clothes-in-space-are-there-any-technical-challenges/659#659)
- [A: What are the choices today for orbital mechanics simulation software?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/646/what-are-the-choices-today-for-orbital-mechanics-simulation-software/3073#3073)
- [A: What are the practical limitations of gravitational assists?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3569/what-are-the-practical-limitations-of-gravitational-assists/3571#3571)
- [A: What are these orientations called in orbit?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3631/what-are-these-orientations-called-in-orbit/3658#3658)
- [A: What factors determine whether a spacecraft/probe/satellite uses gyroscopes or propellant th…](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/4091/what-factors-determine-whether-a-spacecraft-probe-satellite-uses-gyroscopes-or-p/4092#4092)
- [A: What is feathering?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1854/what-is-feathering/1855#1855)
- [A: What is the point of rotation of an “umbrella ship”](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3172/what-is-the-point-of-rotation-of-an-umbrella-ship/3173#3173)
- [A: What is the purpose of the jets of water often under rocket engines during launch?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1551/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-jets-of-water-often-under-rocket-engines-during-launc/1552#1552)
- [A: What is the smallest operational artificial satellite?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/925/what-is-the-smallest-operational-artificial-satellite/1737#1737)
- [A: What software language was used to program the martian rovers Spirit, Opportunity and Curios…](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3715/what-software-language-was-used-to-program-the-martian-rovers-spirit-opportunit/3716#3716)
- [A: What was the source of the fluid in Luca Parmitano's suit?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1625/what-was-the-source-of-the-fluid-in-luca-parmitanos-suit/1626#1626)
- [A: What went wrong, Falcon 9 1.1 first flight with first stage landing attempt?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2223/what-went-wrong-falcon-9-1-1-first-flight-with-first-stage-landing-attempt/2224#2224)
- [A: What would a lunar eclipse look like from the surface of the moon?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/5561/what-would-a-lunar-eclipse-look-like-from-the-surface-of-the-moon/5566#5566)
- [A: What Would Happen if We (Theoretically) Send a Drone With a Camera Inside a Black Hole?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2166/what-would-happen-if-we-theoretically-send-a-drone-with-a-camera-inside-a-blac/2184#2184)
- [A: What would the atmospheric conditions of Venus sound like on its surface?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2459/what-would-the-atmospheric-conditions-of-venus-sound-like-on-its-surface/2465#2465)
- [A: Why did the LLTV have a service ceiling of 6,000 ft?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3336/why-did-the-lltv-have-a-service-ceiling-of-6-000-ft/3337#3337)
- [A: Why didn't the Space Shuttle have a launch escape system?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1325/why-didnt-the-space-shuttle-have-a-launch-escape-system/1379#1379)
- [A: Why do they say “go” and “no go”](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/4306/why-do-they-say-go-and-no-go/4314#4314)
- [A: Why hasn't NASA planted a stationary lab on Mars yet?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/4332/why-hasnt-nasa-planted-a-stationary-lab-on-mars-yet/4338#4338)
- [A: Why is a stick required to operate Soyuz's computer?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/4114/why-is-a-stick-required-to-operate-soyuzs-computer/4116#4116)
- [A: Why is the Far Side of the Moon so different than the Near Side?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2631/why-is-the-far-side-of-the-moon-so-different-than-the-near-side/2637#2637)
- [A: Why multiple lightning towers at launch sites?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/6486/why-multiple-lightning-towers-at-launch-sites/6487#6487)
- [A: Why the Apollo 11 spaceflight didn't (or why looks like it didn't) blow the dust away?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1691/why-the-apollo-11-spaceflight-didnt-or-why-looks-like-it-didnt-blow-the-dust/3651#3651)
- [A: Why the Apollo 11 spaceflight didn't (or why looks like it didn't) blow the dust away?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1691/why-the-apollo-11-spaceflight-didnt-or-why-looks-like-it-didnt-blow-the-dust/1693#1693)
- [A: Why the non-symmetric design of rocket nozzles?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/5347/why-the-non-symmetric-design-of-rocket-nozzles/5349#5349)
- [A: Will Rosetta have to adjust its orbit around Chury due to the comet's coma and tails?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/768/will-rosetta-have-to-adjust-its-orbit-around-chury-due-to-the-comets-coma-and-t/4082#4082)
- [A: Would terraforming Venus destroy its ionosphere?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/would-terraforming-venus-destroy-its-ionosphere/3655#3655)

---

In total, currently (Jan. 2, 2015), 134 individual posts (42 questions and 92 answers), representing 125 unique threads, link to YouTube videos.

Comment: @TildalWave - for the record, wholeheartedly support this featreq.