# How to show this particular tweeted (GIF?) in a question? - trouble downloading

Tags: support

This is a cool video/GIF/moving image of a satellite transiting the moon as seen from the Royal observatory.

I don't understand exactly what I'm looking at from a web point of view - if I try to right-click and save I get 750kB of HTML.

How can I display/embed this cool moving image in a Question in space SE? Is there a way to extract a GIF?

https://twitter.com/ROGAstronomers/status/720254837095575552

Manual screenshot, showing the speeding satellite as a little blurred white thing, and the letters GIF in the bottom left corner. It turns out (pointed out by [@kimholder below](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/742/12102)) that it's a Faux-GIF!
[image: screen shot of tweet]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like while it may seem to be a GIF, it actually isn't - it's been [converted by Twitter to a MP4](http://techcrunch.com/2014/06/19/gasp-twitter-gifs-arent-actually-gifs/). So, there is no way you can post that in an answer, other than as a still image with a link. Only [YouTube videos](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/572/4660) will play in Space Exploration answers.

It looks like your only option is to find the original GIF. It lists a lot of stuff about the source, so that seems plausible. An animated GIF will display properly.

Comment: Thanks for finding that tidbit - I've added a screenshot and updated the description. Faux-GIF! OK I'll keep searching. Probably someone will have reverse-Fauxed it back into a GIF somewhere.

Comment: I've gone ahead and [asked a question](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/14838/12102) with a static screenshot. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. If i get a bit of time in the evening, i might try my hand at finding that GIF too.